# Official API for typing.Generic.__orig_bases__

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

I have a generic type for which I'd like to retrieve at runtime the type of its type variable.

The following snippet runs well, but it uses `Generic.__orig_bases__` which is not an official API (its use is discouraged in [PEP 560](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#mro-entries) that defines it).

Is there an official API to retrieve it? And if not, is there another (officially supported) way for me to code `get_t` in this example?

```py
import typing


T = typing.TypeVar("T")


class MyGeneric(typing.Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def get_t(cls) -> type[T]:
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:
            if typing.get_origin(base) is MyGeneric:
                return typing.get_args(base)[0]
        raise RuntimeError("didn't work :(")


class IntImplementation(MyGeneric[int]):
    pass


assert IntImplementation.get_t() is int
```

Comment: There's no official introspection API for `__orig_bases__`, but I suspect you can consider this stable enough, at least for 2-3 versions.

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to post this as an answer - if that's what then it is I'll accept it (until it changes hopefully!)

Comment: I think you misinterpreted what PEP 560 says: _"These two method names are reserved [...] and any other use is discouraged."_ This refers to the methods `__class_getitem__` and `__mro_entries__`. It technically does not say anywhere that using the `__orig_bases__` attribute is discouraged. But it is not documented anywhere else, so blindly relying on it to remain stable is probably still a bad idea. As long as you keep that in mind, you should be good.